# How do you specify in a turn with an Adaptive Card the Dialog Intent that should respond to it

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards, adaptive-dialogs

I would like my adaptive card's actions to be handled by a specific intent in my adaptive dialog. 
What's the way to get that done?

Comment: Hello, can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I've specified ".Intent" on the card's json body, both in the body directly and as part of the data array that an action can include on submit.

Comment: Great, can you edit some examples into your question in accordance with the asking guidelines? Post some links to the documents you're following too. Help us reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up using the none Intent - [OnIntent("None")]. 
While in there, I used the If common expression to check for a specific token in the activity's value,

```
Condition = "turn.activity.value.decision == 'join'",
```

and make a choice about the next dialog based on that.